# How can I make jQuery to check multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

The jQuery code below works very well and checks for input values based on conditions, but for the ESNList text field in the HTML form, many ESNs (numbers) can be entered and separated by a comma in the same text field. How can I make so jQuery makes sure that all the numbers entered on the same text field still match the condition for ESNList? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(function () {
    
    
    $(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
      $(":text").keyup(function(){
        var enteredData = $(this).val()
        console.log(enteredData);
        if (enteredData == "") {
          $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
        } else {
          $(this).css("border", "inherit");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList"){
          esnList = parseInt(enteredData);
          switch (true){
            case ( esnList >= 986329 && esnList <= 999999):
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                break;
            case ( esnList >= 660000 && esnList <= 699999):
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                break;
            case ( esnList >= 200000 && esnList <= 299999):
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
                break;
            case ( esnList >= 1202114 && esnList <= 1299999):
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                break;
          }
          
        }
      });
      });
    </script> </head>
    <body>
    <form id="provision">
        ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
        ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
         Unit Model:   <select name="STxName" id="ddl_StxName">
        <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
        <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
        <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
         <option value="trackpack">Trackpack</option>
        <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
        <option value="smartone">Smartone</option>
        <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
        </select> <br />
        RTU Model Type:
         <select name="rtumodel" id ="ddl_rtumodel">
        <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
        <option value="both">Both</option>
        <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
        <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
        </select> <br />
        <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what if the group of numbers contains different cases? Please define conditions more precisely for group of numbers and what you want to test them against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the list by a comma delimiter and validate each individual element.

```
$.each(enteredData.split(","), function(i, str){
    var esnList = +str;
    /* enter validation here */
});
```

Comment: How can I make it so all the data entered must match the condition for ESNList otherwise it alerts the user that the number entered must be in the same range as the other numbers ?

Comment: @php_addict, you just need to move your validation there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `parseInt()` directly on `enteredData` you would first use

```
esnList = enteredData.split(',');
```

and then you can go over that array with a loop, using `parseInt()` and performing your checks or use the map function of your favorite JS library for that like Alexander did.

Plain JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < esnList.length; i++) {
    ... // parseInt(esnList[i]) and perform checks
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.each(esnList, function(i, esn) {
    ... // parseInt(esn) and perform checks
});
```

Comment: can you show me how I could do it in Jquery with a loop , I am pretty new to this

Answer (score 0):

Expecting clean, well-formed data from a user in an input field is optimistic - even with visual instructions.

Without going into security and sanitation lets assume the user has put in a well formed comma separated list:

```
153, 189, 635
```

You will need to write a function that takes the input value of the input element and then do a split() on the variable. This will give you an array which you can loop over to check the value against your criteria.

Comment: @Alexander .. can you give me an example ?  I'm so new to Javascript and Jquery .. I'd greatly appreciate nit it .

Comment: @php_addict, regarding this specific answer you should ask HankHendrix, not me