# How could I accomplish this with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so Jquery checks that ESNStart and ESNEND in the HTML form are in the same range otherwise it throws an alert saying that both numbers need to be in the same range to the user after typing in the value for  ESNEnd ??
I still don't understand how I could also make it so ESNList gets checked for all its multiple values entered in the text field to be in the same range otherwise it also throws an alert to the user to enter a number in the same range as shown by the if statements ? A fiddle demonstrating this would help me learn so much , thanks a bunch !

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
                $(":text").keyup(function() {
                    var enteredData = $(this).val()
                    console.log(enteredData);
                    if (enteredData == "") {
                        $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("border", "inherit");
                    }
                    if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList") {
                        esnList = parseInt(enteredData);
                        switch (true) {
                            case (esnList >= 986329 && esnList <= 999999):
                                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
                                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                                break;
                            case (esnList >= 660000 && esnList <= 699999):
                                $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
                                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                                break;
                            case (esnList >= 200000 && esnList <= 299999):
                                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
                                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
                                break;
                            case (esnList >= 1202114 && esnList <= 1299999):
                                $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
                                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="provision">ESNList:
            <input type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" />
            <br />ESN Start:
            <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" />
            <br />ESN End:
            <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" />
            <br />UnitName:
            <input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30" />
            <br />Unit Model:
            <select name="STxName" id="ddl_StxName">
                <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
                <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
                <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
                <option value="trackpack">Trackpack</option>
                <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
                <option value="smartone">Smartone</option>
                <option value="smartoneb">SmartOneB</option>
            </select>
            <br />RTU Model Type:
            <select name="rtumodel" id="ddl_rtumodel">
                <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
                <option value="both">Both</option>
                <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
                <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question? Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you already know what you're doing, just add some if statements to check the range of ESNEND and ESNSTART. Can you rephrase?

Also btw, you have Start written twice in your HTML tags.

Comment: @Brandi I am trying to make ESNStart and ESNEnd be in the same range  as mentioned by the if statements below otherwise it throws an alert that ESNEnd and ESNStart should be in the same range .. for example 1 -90

Comment: It looks like you already know how to do it, though. I'm not sure what piece you're missing? You can get the handle via JQuery with the id (like you do with the other fields), use if or switch statements to compare the values (like you do with ESNList), and if they are not in the satisfactory range, you can use the alert() function to tell the user to reenter the data. If needed you could wipe the value out of the textbox as well, or put validation on the submit so they cannot enter bad values.

Comment: If someone enters 2 for ESNStart and 100 for ESNEnd when the range of ESNStart and ESNEnd should be between 1 and 10 , it should alert the user to type something between 1 and 10 for ESNEnd if u type anything above 10 for ESNEnd .. Values of ESNSTART AND ESNEND should be in the same range as mentioned in the if statement ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Jquery to check multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593480/how-can-i-make-jquery-to-check-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

I created some methods that seem to work, although I haven't created groups of numbers that are out of range.

I strongly suggest you don't allow user to enter comma separated lists as it will be hard to point to user the invalid entries. It would be a lot cleaner having each number in it's own input. You can easily add a button for "Add new number" and create a new input for it.

I used arrays to store ranges and the values for the valid range that get changed for other fields. This module is not trivial and suggest you create a testing sandbox with a wide variety of numbers you can test with.

```
$('#ESNList').keyup(function(){
    var enteredData = $(this).val();
    $(this).removeClass('valid');
    if( enteredData == ''){
        return;
    }
    if(hasMultipleValues(enteredData)){
        var range=rangeCheckMultipleNumbers(enteredData)
      if( range===false){
        log('Numbers not in same range');
        return;
      } else{
          setRangeValues(range);

        $(this).addClass('valid');
      }
    }
    var rangeIdx = getRangeIndex(enteredData);
    if(rangeIdx===false){
        log('Number not in range');
    }else{
        setRangeValues(rangeIdx);           
        $(this).addClass('valid');
    }
});

function hasMultipleValues( str){ 
     /* second test for a singel entry with comma at end*/   
    return str.indexOf(',') !=-1 && str.indexOf(',') != str.length-1;   
}

var ranges = [
    [986329, 999999],
    [660000, 699999],
    [200000, 299999],
    [1202114, 1299999]
];

var rangeText = [
    ["stx2", "globalstar"],
    ["mmt", "globalstar"],
    ["stm3", "stmcomtech"],
    ["smartone", "globalstar"]
]


/* returns range index if all in same range, otherwise returns false*/
function rangeCheckMultipleNumbers(str) {
    var nums = str.split(',');
    var rangeMatch = true; /* clean array to remove empty values if extra commas*/
    nums = $.grep(array, function(item, index) {
        return parseInt(item);
    });

    var groupRange = getRangeIndex(nums[0]);
    if(nums.length > 1) {
        for(i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(!checkSameRange(nums[i - 1], nums[i])) {
                rangeMatch = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return rangeMatch ? groupRange : false;
}


function setRangeValues(rangeIndex) {
    $("#ddl_StxName").val(rangeText[rangeIndex][0]);
    $("#ddl_rtumodel").val(rangeText[rangeIndex][1]);
}

function checkSameRange(num1, num2) {
    return getRangeIndex(parseInt(num1, 10)) == getRangeIndex(parseInt(num2, 10));
}
/* returns false if out of range, otherwise returns range index*/
function getRangeIndex(num) {
    var idx = false;
    $.each(ranges, function(i, range) {
        if(num >= range[0] && num <= range[1]) {
            idx = i;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return idx;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hXsQ8/1/

Comment: for this assignment , it's required that numbers are separated with comma , yet in the same range .. Thanks a lot for trying to help though

Comment: when I separate values with a comma in ESNList text field , it works for the first input , but it doesn't works for the second .. it doesn't check for the second input in the same text field after a comma .

Comment: I only bound event to one input for demo. Create an update of demo with a bunch of sample lists can use to cut paste for testing